# Trying to get property 'service' of non-object in a Laravel script

Tags: php, html, laravel

I installed a Laravel, Now I want use from a site api and see its services in my site, but when I open "API SERVICES PAGE", this error is appeared:

> "Trying to get property 'service' of non-object (View: /home/core/resources/views/admin/apiServices.blade.php)"

for this line:

> ```
>  <td>{{ isset($item->service->id) ? $item->service->id : $item->service}}</td>
> ```

My page codes:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="tile">
                <h3 class="tile-title">API Services List</h3>
                <table class="table table-hover">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Serial</th>
                        <th>Service ID</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Category</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Min</th>
                        <th>Max</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($items as $key => $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ (int) $key+1 }}</td>
                            <td>{{ isset($item->service->id) ? $item->service->id : $item->service}}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->category }}</td>
                            <td>{{ isset($item->rate) ? $item->rate : $item->price_per_k }} $</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->min }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->max }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And a part its controller:

```
public function apiService(){
        $api = ApiSetting::first();
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api->url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "api_tokens=".$api->key."&action=services");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
        $items = json_decode($server_output);
        return view('admin.apiServices', compact('items'));
    }
```

Comment: `$item` isn't an object. `<?php dd($item); ?>` to find out what it is.

Comment: I'm confused, can U explain one more?

Comment: `$item` isn't an object, so you can't get the property `service` from it. You need to figure out exactly what `$item` is first.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information in your question.

It looks to me like you are attempting to access a relational object without setting up the relationship in your model.

I don't know how you want to access services from an item but you may want something like this in your Item model

```
public function Service() 
{
    return $this->hasmany('App\Service');
}
```

Please reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question and attached the controller codes, please recheck it, because I nut understand your mean. thank u

Comment: I am pretty sure I know what your problem is. Can you provide the output when you do: return $items in your controller.

Comment: Excuse me, but I do not know much about laravel
How can I check this question?